# Classic ASP bizarre SQL error

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic, odbc, database-connection

I am connecting to a Access DB, with following Conn String

`Conn.Open "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=\\server\share\Data\PFWTRAN.MDB"`

The following SQL works fine;

```
SQLIn =     "SELECT Date, Time " & _
            "FROM Transactions " & _
            "WHERE TokenNumber = " & TokenNo & " " & _
            "AND Date >= " & FromDateG & " " & _
            "AND Direction = -1 " & _               
            "ORDER BY Date, TransactionNumber;"
```

However, I want rows where Transactions.Exception = 0, yet when I add this AND condition, the script fails when the RS is opened;

`error '80004005' /path/.../.../...asp, line 97`

If I remove the AND condition, it works again.

Even If I try and put 'Exception' in the SELECT section, it won't run and gives me that error.

Why would the inclusion of one field cause such an error? I read the error is due to permissions, but my permissions are fine as the SQL works without this one field in it.

Any clues?

It is a very old Access 95 database (or even earlier), perhaps I need to change connection provided?

Comment: Are you quoting the date value? Output the actual SQL string generated and paste it into a new Query in MS Access. Se what it says there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*However, I want rows where Transaction.Exception = 0, yet when I add this AND condition, the script fails when the RS is opened*"

But Transaction.Exception refers to a different table than the one your query uses.

```
FROM Transactions
```

`Date`, `Time`, and `Exception` are [Problem names and reserved words in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).  Enclose those names in square brackets, or prefix them with the table name/alias.

Consider switching your approach to use a parameter query ... and feed it `TokenNo` and `FromDateG` values as parameters, rather than building their values into the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Thanks! I enclosed the field name in [ ] and it worked! p.s. that was a type re. Transactions table name.